# Optional("") being saved in database

Tags: swift

In Swift 4.2 I have the following method

```
cell.onPartNumberTapped = { [weak self] in
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter New Part Number", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Add/Edit Part Number"
            textField.text = ""
        }

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) { (action) in
            let textField = alert.textFields![0]

            let parameters = [
                "id": component.id,
                "part_number": textField.text as Any
                ] as [String : Any];

            Alamofire.request(global.API_URL + "components/edit_pn", method: .post, parameters: parameters as Parameters ).responseJSON { [weak self]
                response in

                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    //
                } else {
                    self?.showMessage(messageToDisplay: "Unable to connect to service.")
                } // end if
            }
        }

        alert.addAction(action)

        self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

The value being saved after the AJAX call is

```
Optional("S65-5366-2L-1X")
```

Is it normal to have to use a regex in the backend to remove that or did I miss something in the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the dictionary with `parameters as Parameters` converts the optional value  that is `textField.text` to the string `Optional("whatever was in the text field")`. To avoid that, convert the optional value to a non-optional like this:

```
let parameters = [
    "id": component.id,
    "part_number": textField.text ?? "" // if nil use the empty string, otherwise unwrap
] as [String : Any];
```

Note that your client should probably inform the user about an empty text field instead of using a default value.